# Recording On Page at User Discretion?

Tags: user-feedback, diary-studies

I work purely on heavy use intranet applications. Due to the usage and frustration with many of these applications, users are more than willing to provide detailed feedback. We have been throwing around the idea of a recording service that can be embedded on web apps and used to allow users to record their feedback, issues and what not with the application.

This would function sort of like a hybrid between a feedback button and a digital diary study. It would be one click to record audio/video and screen (like Morae and Camtasia) and one click to finish, with a single confirmation to "submit" their recording to the application team.

My question is, does anyone know if something like this, or close to it, exists?

Comment: but why would anybody record the entire screen and send the data in video format when the feedback can be submitted otherwise. I am confused? On the reason for recording the screen. To send feedback?

Comment: A bunch of them actually. http://screen-capture-software-review.toptenreviews.com/

Comment: @pzv because if a bug is easily replicable, recording it may be easier than writing a highly specific report, and better than writing a vague report (e.g., "I tried to log in but it's not working").

Answer (score 1):

I think your users can use Problem Steps Recorder and email to you.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-use-problem-steps-recorder

Or you can create an app for this using command line options: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b78253b1-6e38-4563-9efa-4973414e9a75/problems-step-recorder-psrexe-command-line-options?forum=w7itprogeneral

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SessionRecord](https://sessionrecord.com) (Disclaimer: I am the author of the tool)

You can self host the recorder(available as a docker image) inside your intranet and include the recorder into you web app when needed.
Web pages along with all user actions are recorded and will be available as a video for playback.

Recording audio is not supported though.